# array of pointers to 2D array

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

What would be the correct way to hold an array of pointers to a bunch of 2D arrays of the variable?

```
const int arr0[][4] = {{10, 11, 12, 13},    \
                       {14, 15, 16, 17},    \
                       {18, 19, 20, 21},    \
                       {22, 23, 24, 25}};
const int arr1[][4] = {{80, 81, 82, 83},    \
                       {84, 85, 86, 87},    \
                       {88, 89, 90, 91},    \
                       {92, 93, 94, 95}};

int *ptr[2];     // Elements of ptr should point to any array size
ptr[0] = arr0;   // this give Warning C4047 '=': 'bool *' differs in levels of indirection from 'const bool (*)[4]'
```

Where do I miss * / & / (  )   ??

Thanks

edit:
As I don't know in build time the actual size of arr0/1 (can vary), I want to hold two pointers `(*ptr[2] ?)` referring to arr0/arr1 and access their elements using some pointer arithmetic, something like (assuming I have width=4 stored dynamically):

```
int out_2_3 = *(ptr[0] + 2*width + 3) + *(ptr[1] + 2*width + 3);
```

//  desired: 20+90

Comment: The warning says bool, your code only has int. Is there a copy-paste-edit problem? Did you copy the exact code which causes the quoted warnings?

Comment: The backslashes are redundant.

Comment: "*Elements of ptr should point to any array size*" <- that's impossible. You need `int ((*ptr)[4])[2]` or something like that.

Comment: The type of `ptr[0]` is `int*`, while the type of `arr0` is (or can decay to) `int**`. What exactly are you hoping to achieve by assigning an `int**` value into an `int*` variable?

Comment: @klutt Are you sure?

Comment: @goodvibration `arr0` does not decay to `int**`

Comment: @goodvibration wrooong! The type of `arr0`, evaluated as a pointer, is `int (*)[4]`. See my previous comment.

Comment: cant you use like this,    `int (*ptr)[4];    ptr[2] = {arr0, arr1};`?

Comment: @LethalProgrammer typedef?

Comment: Yes, I missed typedef. `typedef int (*ptr)[4]; ptr[2] = {arr0, arr1};`

Comment: And an identifier for the actual array...

Comment: @LethalProgrammer, 4 is not always 4. The 2D arrays can be of any size. Does this affect your answer

Comment: @EugeneSh. I understand that braces are redundant, they were just added for clarity. If I understand correctly arr0 is indeed pointer (int*) to a contiguous block of memory. I hope that the braces do not break this. Correct ?

Comment: @eyalasko you can't have pointers to arrays with **different** second dimension in one array -- the type of the pointers would differ! That's what I wrote in my very first comment. If you take a second to think about it: All dimensions of an array except for the first one must be present in the type information, so the compiler can calculate the correct offset from the indices you give. So, a pointer to a 2d array with second dimension `4` has the type `int (*)[4]`. You need a **different idea / design**!